# Latent Variable - Items with different scales

Tags: regression, latent-variable

I want to measure the latent variable risk tolerance. Therefore, I use a total of 6 items. Afterward, I would like to use the latent variable in a linear regression model, however, I don't know how to summarize the 6 items to come up with the variable that I can use in the regression model.

The problem is that the 6 items have different scales. More precisely:

- First item has a scale from 1 to 5
- Second item has a scale from 1 to 7
- Third item has a scale from 1 to 6
- Fourth item has a scale from 1 to 3
- Fifth item has a scale from 1 to 2
- Sixth item has a scale from 1 to 2

Can I just sum up all the scores and take the sum as the input variable for my regression model? Or can I use factor analysis for that purpose? Or what are the best practices to solve that problem?

EDIT: The item responses are ordinal

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are item responses ordinal or continuous? This will help me with a response I am working on.

Comment: The responses are ordinal

Comment: @R_user123 FYI :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, taking the sum could be one approach. However, if your sample is sufficiently large, you have many options. If you search for [structural equation modeling (SEM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) with categorical variables, you should find the best practices you are looking for (e.g., [check this tutorial](https://personality-project.org/r/tutorials/summerschool.14/rosseel_sem_cat.pdf); also see Cai, 2013; and Edwards, Wirth, & Houts, 2012).

**References**

Cai, L. (2013). Factor analysis of tests and items.

Edwards, M. C., Wirth, R. J., Houts, C. R., & Xi, N. (2012). Categorical data in the structural equation modeling framework.